# Twitter API trends function errors

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to learn social web mining from this python book entitled Mining the social web, and I'm getting on the first few functions, here's my output:

> > > import twitter
> > >       CONSUMER_KEY = ''
> > >       CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
> > >       OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''
> > >       OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
> > >       auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY,   CONSUMER_SECRET)
> > >       twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
> > >       print twitter_api
> > >           
> > >       WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
> > >       US_WOE_ID = 23424977
> > >       world_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > >           File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter/api.py", line 245, in **call**
> > >           return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data, _timeout)
> > >           File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter/api.py", line 276, in _handle_response
> > >           raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)
> > >       twitter.api.TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 400 for URL: 1.1/trends/place.json using parameters: (id=1&oauth_consumer_key=&oauth_nonce=9996743856969920690&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1406787153&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=NAVC2M%2FtUQRL3xtuWZRqsuP1rCg%3D)
> > >       details: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

What seems to be the problem here, how can I use this function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should get access token before accessing the twitter url. Follow this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/631) to get the access token.

Comment: I've been having some issues with that also, when I created the access token, I went to the URL and got this error: Failed to validate oauth signature and token. Why am I getting that, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: most of the times this has to do with your system's time stamp (where you are executing the script) should match with server time stamp

Comment: Thanks user3, I'm on Linux Mint so how can I change it so my system's time stamp matches the servers?